# Adding web contents to pages in Liferay Portal

Tags: liferay, portal

I am new to Liferay, how to add specific web content to only single page.for example i have 2 pages like Financial Service and Products.I have related web contents for those two pages.If i add those web contents to pages,both the contents are displaying in both of the pages.

Comment: I think you are talking about adding web-content display portlet on the pages for showing web-content? Can you elaborate a little more in your question with examples and the steps you followed to adding the web-contents on the pages. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add a page on your portal
http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.0/administration/-/ai/page-creation-and-manageme-2

Then you can add two **web-content portlets** pointing to those 2 pages.

Comment: Hey Thanks i followed that link before,how to go to Asset Selection option.any path ??